# Javascript multiple timer countdowns

Tags: javascript, timer

I have a page which is a list of products loaded from the database. Each product has a date field that is also loaded from the database. Each product is contained within a div and a countdown timer script is also loaded within that div. The date associated with the product is used to count the timer down. This date is set to a hidden field with the div which the script can access.So each product div basically looks like this:

```
<div id="prod1">
<input type="hidden" value"targetdate1"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="countdown.js"></script>
</div>

<div id="prod2">
<input type="hidden" value"targetdate2"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="countdown.js"></script>
</div>

<div id="prod3">
<input type="hidden" value"targetdate3"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="countdown.js"></script>
</div>

<div id="prod4">
<input type="hidden" value"targetdate4"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="countdown.js"></script>
</div>
 .......
```

So, essentially the script will be loaded multiple times in a page. And each script should only read the hidden field contained within its own div. I tried to find a way to do this using jquery selectors/javascript but nothing works.

Comment: It's amazing how many times we have to say this on SO, but please, post some code.  Show us what is in countdown.

Comment: Also, you have a typo.  It's `value="countdowndate"`

Comment: Right off, i think you should just have a function, loaded one time, that takes a param, for the div and the date, this way you would not have to include the same script so many times.

Comment: I am using Robert Hashemian's script. http://scripts.hashemian.com/js/countdown.js I should emphasize the issue is not with the script. The issue is when I have to set the target date. The product list page has multiple products, therefore multiple target dates and multiple product divs. Each script loaded should only read the targetdate, which is in the hidden field, that is associated with the specific product. Thats where the issue is.

Comment: nycynik, even if i were to create a function, this function will be loaded once but called multiple times by multiple products. each function call must be able to select the hidden tag specific to a product. This is not possible with generic selectors such as ('input') which would return a collection of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in your countdown.js :

```
document.getElementsByTagName("script")[pos].parentElement  // pos will the serial number of the script tag
```

Now once the div is seelected you can work on it.

Comment: Where would this call need to be placed. If its before the coutdown script, then it the script tags wouldn't be part of the DOM yet. And after the script, the would have already run and the target date wouldn't be set.

Comment: I couldn't find a solution, but found another script that was able to do what I needed: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html